# Asp mvc 4 EF Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository

I have the following code and I would like to know how can I retrieve the data from the repository, here is my code, any advice will be appreciate, thanks

My Controller:

```
 namespace Diploma.WebUI.Controllers
 {
   public class StudentController : Controller
   {
     EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext();

     public ViewResult Student()
     {
        var student = context.Students.Include(p => p.Group);
        return View(student.ToList());
     }
   }
 }
```

My Repository:

```
namespace Diploma.Domain.Concrete
{
 public class EFStudentRepository : IStudentRepository
 {
    EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext();

     public IEnumerable<Student> Students
     {
       get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
     }

     public IEnumerable<Group> Groups
     {
       get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
     }
  }
```

and My Abstract Class

```
   namespace Diploma.Domain.Abstract
  {
     public interface IStudentRepository
     {
       IEnumerable<Student> Students { get;}
       IEnumerable<Group> Groups { get;} 
     }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean to convert everything to the repository? do you mean how to retrieve data from the repository and show the data in the view?

Comment: I would like to do all this with the help of the pattern repository.